# BIRT - Expression for Visibility doesn't work

Tags: expression, visibility, birt

The visibility expression for an object in BIRT doesn't work.
I bind the Dataset on the Grid ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gFs8.jpg)). There will be a black dot in each Cell. It will show if the Condition is true (see example picture: [Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fba2m.jpg))

My Expression / Condition for Visibility of the object (see [expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xq0G.jpg))

```
row["Achievement"]=3 && row["Behavior"]=1
```

Why is it not working? I also tried different syntax e.g. ==3, ='3' and so on. The number is an Integer.So, normally not needed to treat it like a string.

Comment: The syntax your are using is syntactically valid, but obviously wrong. Remember that "=" is an assignment in Javascript. Thus you should use "==", not "=". And of course you have to take into account the data type of your row variables.

Comment: ... and binding a dataset to a Grid is possible, but only makes sense if the data set returns exactly one row. Probably you want to use a grid inside a list, or a table instead of a grid.

Answer (score 0):

solved it... couple of mistakes

1. "==" is correct
2. Version 4.3 is very sensitive. So, High commas help... either " or '
3. The logic was wrong as well. The right answer was also using a || insteadt of &&

The solution, which works:

```
row["Achievement"]=="3" || row["Behavior"]=="2"
```